# Books On Cryptography from Very Basics to Very Advanced

Tags: java, cryptography

From Long back I wanted to learn cryptography and I wanted to become an expert in that. I wanted to learn most of the cryptography algorithms (hashing, encryption, decryption and cracking). After learning the concepts I wanted to implement some of the algorithms using Java. (Even there is JCE API but I am interested to create a kind of one).

Please provide me list of books in order

Books for learning cryptographic concepts (therotical)
books for implementing cryptographic concepts (Practical).

Comment: If the book gives graphical representation then i will be very happy.............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of my favourites:

- **[Cryptography Decrypted](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201616475)

  (theory, basic)**
  [image: Cryptography Decrypted]

Excellent diagrams and explanations of concepts and algorithms

---

- **[Secret and Lies](http://www.schneier.com/book-sandl.html)

  (security, general reading)**
  [image: Cryptography Decrypted]

Another book by Schneier which is more about Security than Cryptography. In other words, why cryptography (by itself) cannot guarantee security. In my Top-Ten list.

In his own words (from the book's [Preface](http://www.schneier.com/book-sandl-pref.html):)

> Seven years ago I wrote another book: Applied Cryptography. In it I described a mathematical utopia: algorithms that would keep your deepest secrets safe for millennia, protocols that could perform the most fantastical electronic interactions-unregulated gambling, undetectable authentication, anonymous cash-safely and securely. In my vision cryptography was the great technological equalizer; anyone with a cheap (and getting cheaper every year) computer could have the same security as the largest government. In the second edition of the same book, written two years later, I went so far as to write: "It is insufficient to protect ourselves with laws; we need to protect ourselves with mathematics."
>
> It's just not true. Cryptography can't do any of that.

---

- **[Malicious Cryptography: Exposing Cryptovirology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764549758)

  (theory, advanced)**
  [image: Malicious Cryptography: Exposing Cryptovirology]

What malicious code that uses cryptography techniques can do (and counter-measures).

---

Answer (score 4):

Well, you've got the classic book by Schneier.

- [Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html)

and he appears to have a new one:

- [Cryptography Engineering](http://www.schneier.com/book-ce.html)

Answer (score 3):

For the theoretical aspects of cryptography I suggest the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) by Menezes, van Oorschot  and Vanstone.  The whole text is available online for personal use, with limitations.